# Gradle build error with Amazon S3 maven repository dependency

Tags: android, react-native, maven, amazon-s3

I am developing an open source [react native library](https://github.com/loadsmart/rn-salesforce-chat) that it's a wrapper for the Salesforce SDK chat. This library uses a Salesforce maven dependency that is hosted on an AWS S3 Bucket.

The problem is that when I try to use this library on a project `SomeProject` that has support for RN autolinking, I keep receiving these build errors:

```
Could not find com.salesforce.service:chat-ui:4.1.1.
Searched in the following locations:
  - file:/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/salesforce/service/chat-ui/4.1.1/chat-ui-4.1.1.pom
  - file:/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/salesforce/service/chat-ui/4.1.1/chat-ui-4.1.1.jar
  - file:/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/salesforce/service/chat-ui/4.1.1/chat-ui-4.1.1.pom
  - file:/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/salesforce/service/chat-ui/4.1.1/chat-ui-4.1.1.jar
  - file:/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/salesforce/service/chat-ui/4.1.1/chat-ui-4.1.1.pom
  - file:/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/salesforce/service/chat-ui/4.1.1/chat-ui-4.1.1.jar
  - file:/Users/user/.m2/repository/com/salesforce/service/chat-ui/4.1.1/chat-ui-4.1.1.pom
  - file:/Users/user/.m2/repository/com/salesforce/service/chat-ui/4.1.1/chat-ui-4.1.1.jar
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/salesforce/service/chat-ui/4.1.1/chat-ui-4.1.1.pom
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/salesforce/service/chat-ui/4.1.1/chat-ui-4.1.1.jar
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/salesforce/service/chat-ui/4.1.1/chat-ui-4.1.1.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/salesforce/service/chat-ui/4.1.1/chat-ui-4.1.1.jar
  - file:/Users/user/Workspace/rhodes/node_modules/react-native/android/com/salesforce/service/chat-ui/4.1.1/chat-ui-4.1.1.pom
  - file:/Users/user/Workspace/rhodes/node_modules/react-native/android/com/salesforce/service/chat-ui/4.1.1/chat-ui-4.1.1.jar
Required by:
    project :app > project :@loadsmart_rn-salesforce-chat
```

To make it work, I need to manually add the S3 maven dependency on my project `SomeProject`. This is bad because I want to give support for RN autolinking in this library.

I also noticed that the `chat-ui` dependency files (`aars`) are being downloaded to `~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/`, instead of the `.m2` or `Android/sdk/extras/...`.

Libraries' `build.gradle`:

```js
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    implementation "com.salesforce.service:chat-ui:4.1.1"
    implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0"
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/salesforcesos.com/android/maven/release'
        }
    }
}
```

So, is there a solution for this problem? I really don't want to force the user to edit their own `build.gradle` file to use the lib.

Comment: did you resolve this issue?

Comment: I'm struggling with the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @MelvynHills We did not find a solution for this. Unfortunately, we ended up manually adding the S3 maven dependency to the project, and describing the necessity of it on the README.